# Eigen c++ linear algebra much slower than numpy -- what is going on?

Tags: numpy, eigen

I compile the following C++ program and compile it with GCC using optimization O3. The resulting matrix inverse is about 3-4 times slower than the equivalent simple numpy code b=np.linalg.inv(a). I was under the impression that Eigen was super fast, so I must be doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Can someone let me know what I can do to improve the code?

The c++ code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <Eigen/LU>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Eigen::MatrixXd;

int main()
{
  const int max_rep = 5;
  const int N=1000;
  MatrixXd inv_m(N,N);

  std::cout << "**** Eigen Library -- matrix inversion speed test ****" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Matrix size = " << N << std::endl;
  
  for(int i=1;i<=max_rep;i++) {
    MatrixXd m = MatrixXd::Random(N,N);
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    inv_m = m.inverse();
    auto stop = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Test no." << std::setw(3) << i;
    std::cout << ", CPU time = " 
          << std::chrono::duration<double>{stop - start}.count()
              << " seconds." << std::endl;
  }  
  return 0;
}
```

The Python code is

```
import numpy as np
import time

for n in range(500, 5001, 500):
a=np.random.rand(n,n)
    t=time.time();
    b=np.linalg.inv(a)
    t=time.time()-t;
    print(f'Size {n=:5d}, {t=:.2f}')
```

I benchmarked a numpy and Eigen codes and was expecting Eigen to be faster, but the result is the opposite. (This is also true for computing eigenvalues, not just for the special case of inverses).

The numpy configration is

```
In [26]: np.show_config()
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
accelerate_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_info:
    libraries = ['blas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/include']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['blas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/include']
    language = c
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_clapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
flame_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'lapack']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
    language = f77
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'lapack', 'blas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/include']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2
    not found = AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_KNL,AVX512_KNM,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL
```

Comment: Well detailed question. Can you also note down the execution times for both?

Comment: Apart from -03 did you also do -DNDEBUG and -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG?

Comment: I won't flag this as duplicate because it might very well be a unique situation, but have you considered a few of those answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193546/worse-performance-using-eigen-than-using-my-own-class?rq=1 

For example, using fixed-dimension matrix class instead of dynamic?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Eigen inverts a 1000x1000 square matrix in 0.33 sec, numpy in 0.08 (I have an old computer, but what matters is the ratio of execution times). Adding -DNDEBUG and -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG does not change the times.

Comment: On my system Eigen is slightly faster (0.16 seconds vs. 0.23). I suspect the difference is because numpy might link against an accelerated BLAS and LAPACK implementation such as MKL. [That's something you could do with Eigen, too.](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html). It would be interesting if you could edit the post and add the output of [`np.show_config()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000164/how-to-check-blas-lapack-linkage-in-numpy-and-scipy)

Comment: As extra data points: If I use Eigen with the OpenMP-parallelized version of MKL, I get 0.024 seconds. Eigen with `-march=native -fopenmp` gets me 0.063 seconds. Without OpenMP, MKL is at 0.049 seconds and Eigen at 0.058

Comment: Many thanks for the useful comments. I've added the output of the numpy.show_config() to the question. I think it uses a generic BLAS and a generic LAPACK.

Comment: That's curious. What happens when you follow the instructions here to use Eigen with the same blas and lapack? https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingBlasLapack.html

Comment: Yes!! Linking to the external BLAS and LAPACK solves the problem. Now numpy and Eigen are about equally fast: 0.09 seconds for Eigen vs 0.08 for numpy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255975/discussion-between-mico-mrkaic-and-homer512).